# Name of a metric space where distance is measured along the circumference/radii of circles centered at the origin

Tags: reference-request, metric-spaces

Years ago I stumbled on the name for a metric on $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that the distance between two points is measured along the shortest path along the radius of a circle (centered at the origin) or along a circle a fixed distance (in the Euclidean sense) from the origin. Examples can be found in the picture below.

*I recall that this metric space was named after a town in Russia where the roads ran circularly around the city center*, but perhaps this recollection is flawed because my quite persistent Google searches were fruitless.

[image: Example of the paths that distance is measured along.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I refer to it as the "Moscow Metric", but on wikipedia it says it's called the "Karlsruhe Metric".

Take a look at google maps, it matches your story.